# How to get rid of MonthEnds type

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to get the delta in months between a starting date and an ending date within Pandas DataFrame. The result is not totally satisfying...

First, the outcome is some sort of Datetime type in the form of <[value] * MonthEnds>.  I can't use this to calculate with. First question is how to convert this to an integer. I tried the .n attribute but then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Second, the outcome is 'missing' one month. Can this be avoided by using another solution/method? Or should I just add 1 month to the answer?

To support my questions I created some simplified code:

```
dates = [{'Start':'1-1-2020', 'End':'31-10-2020'}, {'Start':'1-2-2020', 'End':'30-11-2020'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)
df['Duration'] = (df['End'].dt.to_period('M') - df['Start'].dt.to_period('M'))
df
```

This results in:

```
    Start       End         Duration
0   2020-01-01  2020-10-31  <9 * MonthEnds>
1   2020-02-01  2020-11-30  <9 * MonthEnds>
```

The preferred result would be:

```
    Start       End         Duration
0   2020-01-01  2020-10-31  10
1   2020-02-01  2020-11-30  10
```

Comment: it's unclear if this needs to work for two arbitrary dates (i.e. not only between the month start and ends). The issue is that a `month` is not a well defined unit of time so subtraction is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: You are right, @ALollz. I just tested it with a couple dates and it is not stable. I need to figure out how to solve that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
dates = [{'Start':'1-1-2020', 'End':'31-10-2020'}, {'Start':'1-2-2020', 'End':'30-11-2020'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)
df['Duration'] = (df['End'] - df['Start']).apply(lambda x:x.days//30)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the start-date from the end-date and convert the time delta to months.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = [{'Start':'1-1-2020', 'End':'31-10-2020'}, {'Start':'1-2-2020', 'End':'30-11-2020'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)
df['Duration'] = (df['End']-df['Start']).astype('<m8[M]').astype(int)+1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Start        End  Duration
0 2020-01-01 2020-10-31        10
1 2020-02-01 2020-11-30        10
```